# Alternatives to sysdate in a Check Constraint

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

I'm writing a check constraint which checks whether a value inputted into the Database is greater than the current system date. I've looked through the documentation and you can't use SYSDATE in a check constraint. Is there an alternative way to solve this problem?

Current approach

```
ALTER TABLE s ADD CONSTRAINT s_check CHECK (SYSDATE > s_date);
```

Error message

`ORA-02436: date or system variable wrongly specified in CHECK constraint`

Comment: You need to use a trigger for this in Oracle.

Comment: I assume you only want the date to be greater than the current date when _updating_ the data?  If that's the case then a check constraint is not appropriate because the data is required to _always_ adhere to the check constraint.  What would you expect to happen tomorrow when data that was valid today is suddenly invalid?

Comment: One of the solutions in the linked question (of which yours is a duplicate) is probably what you need. It is NOT the "Correct Answer" marked there, but rather the answer that recommends adding a column to your table design, for `as_of_date` or similar. Populate that column with SYSDATE (which is perfectly legal), and create a table-level check constraint to make sure that the inputted date (in your original data) is greater than the `as_of_date` value. Avoid triggers whenever you can.